# How to pass --illegal-access JVM argument to spring boot maven plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm-arguments, spring-boot-maven-plugin, java-16

I have an application that runs just fine when running this from the command prompt :

```
java -jar --illegal-access=permit target/Something.jar
```

However, configuring my spring boot maven plugin in my `pom.xml` as such gives me the same error as if I ran my cmd without the `illegal-access=permit` part, telling me it is being ignored :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.something.PreMain</mainClass>
        <jvmArguments>
            --illegal-access=permit
        </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

What am I doing wrong?  This app worked perfectly in java 14 and I'm in the process of upgrading to java 16.  Everything still works perfectly except intelliJ not being able to launch it in debug mode due to the missing `illegal-access=permit` JVM argument.

Comment: Just a note of caution: The `--illegal-access` JVM argument will [essentially become a no-op in Java 17](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/403).

Comment: correct, a lot of libraries I use still need to adapt to Java 16 properly, this is temporary

Comment: Try to use the `--illegal-access=warn` (or debug) to see what is breaking.
As it says in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#:~:text=The%20default%20mode%2C%20%2D%2Dillegal,warn%20or%20the%20debug%20modes.) you are using internal stuff that might go away. I'm thinking that it might have gone away if you have problem with java 16 and it works with java 14.

Comment: it works when running from command prompt, it should also work from intelliJ no?

Comment: @Martin If you are running the application via IntelliJ, try adding the arguments in your configuration. You can share the exact steps on how you execute the application in the question and add the IntelliJ tag instead of any other.

Comment: I added the option in the idea64.exe.vmoptions file and no change

Comment: @Martin I thought this problem was with maven. are you having problems running from maven or from intellij, or both? or using maven from intellij?

Comment: I can't run my code from intelliJ because I don't know how to pass JVM arguments to the spring boot maven plugin.  It works just fine outside the IDE because I can just pass the arguments when runnning the java -jar command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to run the application in IntelliJ, you don't need to pass anything into Maven.  In IntelliJ, open the run configuration for your app and under Environment->VM options add --illegal-access=permit.  See the attached image, Main class would be your fully qualified location of your `@SpringBootApplication` class, e.g. com.something.MySpringBootApplication

[image]

When you start your app in debug mode in IntelliJ, you'll see something like

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52737,suspend=y,server=n --illegal-access=permit -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1...`, notice the argument getting passed to your app.

Comment: This does indeed work but that begs the question : does the JvmArguments section in the spring boot maven plugin even do anything?  I would much prefer this configuration reside in POM.xml rather than the intelliJ run configs...

Comment: Yeah, it's not very straightforward.  The jvmArguments option doesn't actually get passed into the top level JVM, but rather to any processes that are forked off of it, from Maven.  So, if you run your app with `mvn spring-boot:run` then those options will be passed to the VM that Maven forks.

Comment: I'll add on to what you mentioned about not wanting to put that configuration in two places, in IntelliJ you can change your run configuration from the spring boot configuration to the maven configuration, the command would simply be `spring-boot:run`.  This, however will not allow you to debug from IntelliJ because the debugger would be attached to the Maven process, and not the process Maven forks (your application).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try putting it in the properties instead. Try this:

```
<properties>
    <jvm.options>--illegal-access=permit</jvm.options>
</properties>
```

Then use it in the plugin as follows:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.something.PreMain</mainClass>
    <compilerArgs>
       <arg>${jvm.options}</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

***Note***: Instead of args, you would need to use argline if you're accessing illegal-access parameter for surefire.